# How to disable retpoline?

Tags: kernel, kernel-parameters

I need to disable retpoline for a use case. I tried adding `noretpoline` to the boot parameter but it doesn't seem to work.
The output after adding noretpoline param:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spectre_v2
Mitigation: Full generic retpoline, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling
```

Kernel: 4.18.0-58.el8.x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable retpoline, you need to disable the Spectre variant 2 mitigations using `spectre_v2=off` on the kernel command line. See [the kernel’s list of parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) for details (that link is specifically for 4.18; for other versions, replace “v4.18” in the URL as appropriate).